# Convert ios img path to blob or file in javascript

Tags: javascript, file, blob

How to convert "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D6326867-A474-481F-B6B4-5A9A6251CC0E/tmp/cdv_photo_013.jpg" to a blob of file in Javascript ?

Comment: You select it on a `<input id="file-input" type="file" accept="image/*">` and then `$('#file-input').get(0).files[0]` returns a blob.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using plugins to crop the picture and it returns just an Uri